# How do I specify how tags in headers are exported to HTML in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

I would like tags in headers (specifically) to export to html as links to a file of the same name, something like:

```
 * My first post is about dogs :DOGS:
```

where `:DOGS:` then exports as

```
<span class="tag">
    <a href="./dogs.html">DOGS</a>
</span>
```

instead of what it currently exports as which is

```
<span class="tag">
    <span class="DOGS">DOGS</span>
</span>
```

I assume another issue I'll have to work through is that I'd need to specify that *some tags* get exported (like ones in headers), while others don't (like ones in bodies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a modified `org-html-format-headline-function` that calls a modified `org-html--tags` function and hook it into the standard HTML exporter by redefining/customizing the variable `org-html-format-headline-function`.

Here's a possible implementation:

```el
#+begin_src elisp
  (defun ndk/org-html-format-headline-function
      (todo _todo-type priority text tags info)
    "Default format function for a headline.
  See `org-html-format-headline-function' for details."
    (let ((todo (org-html--todo todo info))
          (priority (org-html--priority priority info))
          (tags (ndk/org-html--tags tags info)))
      (concat todo (and todo " ")
          priority (and priority " ")
          text
          tags)))

  (defun ndk/org-html--tags (tags info)
    "Format TAGS into HTML.
  INFO is a plist containing export options."
    (when tags
      (format "<span class=\"tag\">%s</span>"
          (mapconcat
           (lambda (tag)
             (format "<a href=\"%s\">%s</a>"
                     (format "./%s.html" (downcase tag))
                     tag))
           tags  "&#xa0;"))))

  ;; (setq org-html-format-headline-function #'org-html-format-headline-default-function)
  (setq org-html-format-headline-function #'ndk/org-html-format-headline-function)
#+end_src
```

If you compare the two functions above with the standard ones in `ox-html.el`, you should be able to see clearly the small differences between them (and how to modify them further if needed).

For testing, the two `setq` forms at the end are convenient: comment one  or the other out to get either the default or the modified behavior. When you are satisfied with the functions, you should probably customize the variable `org-html-format-headline-function` to set the whole thing in stone.